# How to clear value in textfield using XCode UI tests

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, ios-ui-automation, xcode-ui-testing

Performing automation using XCode UI tests. I have a scenario where I need to clear the value in the textfield and enter any new text. I am able to access the text but couldn't able to clear it.

```
app.alerts["abc"].collectionViews.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element(boundBy: 1).children(matching: .textField).element.value
```

Above part of the code gives me the value in the textfield. Is there any way I can clear the value in the textfield using **Swift 3**

Answer (score 3):

This is the bit of code that I use for clearing fields before entering information in them in my UI Tests. If there's a Clear Text button it uses that; otherwise, it enters a string of backspaces sufficient to clear the contents of the field.

```
    if app.buttons["Clear text"].exists {
        app.buttons["Clear text"].tap()
    } else if let fieldValue = field.value as? String {
        // If there's any content in the field, delete it
        var deleteString: String = ""
        for _ in fieldValue.characters {
            deleteString += "\u{8}"
        }
            field.typeText(deleteString)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` of `XCUIElement` is readonly property and there is no way to change it programmatically (only manually using UI interaction). Try

```
textFieldElement.buttons["Clear text"].tap()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let userName = app.textFields["UserName - Login"] //Accessible label identifier
userName.tap()
userName.typeText("hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let textField = app.textFields.element(boundBy: 0)
    textField.tap()
    //Select all text
    textField.tap(withNumberOfTaps: 3, numberOfTouches: 1)
    textField.typeText("2139218938")
    app.buttons["Login"].tap()
```